# Выравнивание плавающих блоков по ширине с float-left

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap4

Использую Bootstrap 4.

Есть стандартный контейнер с вложенными блоками которым присвоено левое обтекание:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

   <div class="col">

    <div class="float-left"></div>

    <div class="float-left"></div>

    <div class="float-left"></div>

   </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Количество блоков не фиксировано и может меняться при перезагрузке.

Ширина блока задана так:

```
 width: 12rem
```

Как сделать, чтобы блоки выравнивались равномерно по ширине родительского элемента и переносились на новую строку если расстояние между блоками становится меньше заданного значения. При этом чтобы расстояние между блоками всех уровней было одинаковым, даже если нижний ряд блоков состоит из меньшего числа блоков, чем верхние.

Comment: `display: grid`

Comment: @Qwertiy отличное решение, напишите - я отмечу как ответ. Спасибо